# testing if my iterator is at the front of the list when decrementing

Tags: c++, linked-list, try-catch

So I need to make try/catch for when the iterator is at the front of the list and the -- operator is used. I've tried checking to see if the iterator is equal to begin() but that doesn't seem to work.

```
template <typename E>
class List : public SLinkedList<E> {

public:
// NOTE THE DIFFERENT LETTER – IT IS ONLY USED HERE! 
// Use E everywhere else! m
// For a nested class, methods are declared and defined *INSIDE*
// the class declaration.
template <typename I>
class Iterator {
public:
    // Give List access to Iterator private fields.
    friend class List<E>;

    // These are the minimum methods needed.
    E operator*() { return nodePosition->elem; } //dereference the iterator and return a value
    Iterator<E> operator++() { 
        try {
            if (nodePosition->next == nullptr)
                throw OutsideList("\nIterator:Error: attempted acess position outside of list.");
            nodePosition = nodePosition->next;
        }
        catch (OutsideList err) {
            cout << err.getError() << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }  //increment the iterator
    Iterator<E> operator--() {
        try {
            if (nodePosition == llist.begin())
                throw OutsideList("\nIterator:Error: attempted acess position outside of list.");
            nodePosition = nodePosition->prev;
        }
        catch (OutsideList err) {
            cout << err.getError() << endl;
        }
        return *this;

}  //decrement the iterator
    bool operator==(const Iterator<E> p) {
        return (nodePosition == p)
    }  //test equality of iterators
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<E> p) {
        return (nodePosition != p.nodePosition);
    }   //test inequality of iterators


private:
    // Constructors & destructor here since only want List class to access.

    // List constructor called from List::begin(). Use initializer list or
    // create class copy constructor and assignment overload.
    Iterator(const List<E>* sl) : llist(sl) {
        nodePosition = sl->head;
    }

    // Class fields.
    const List<E>* llist;     //give Iterator class a handle to the list
    Node<E>* nodePosition;  //abstracted position is a pointer to a node

}; /** end Iterator class **/

   /* The Iterator class is now fully defined. The rest of these
   statements must go AFTER the Iterator class or the compiler
   won’t have complete information about their data types.
   */

   // REQUIRED: While not necessary for the code to work, my test suite needs
   // this defined. Create a less cumbersome name for Iterator<E>. Use 
   // anywhere you would have used List<E>::Iterator<E> in class List. Allows 
   // this syntax in main() -- List<int>::iterator instead of List<int>::Iterator<int>.
typedef typename List<E>::Iterator<E> iterator;

/***    All method declarations and fields for the List class go here.
Any method that returns an iterator must be defined here.
***/
iterator begin() const {  //return an iterator of beginning of list
                          // Call iterator constructor with pointer to List that begin() was 
                          // called with.
    return iterator(this);
}
E back();
E pop_back();
void push_back(const E e);
iterator end() const {
    iterator itr = iterator(this);
    while (itr.nodePosition->next != nullptr) {
        ++itr;
    }
    ++itr;
    return itr;
}
void insert(int itr, E elem);
void erase(int itr);
```

};

Answer (score 1):

```
bool operator==(const Iterator<E> p) {
    return (nodePosition == p);
}
```

does not seem right. The main problem is that you are comparing `nodePosition` of the current object, the object on the LHS, with the object on the RHS.

1. You don't need `Iterator<E>`. Just `Iterator` is good enough.
2. There is no point in making the argument `const Iterator`. It can be just `Iterator`, or better `const Iterator&`.
3. Make the member function a `const` member function.
4. The comparison needs to be made with the corresponding `nodePosition`s.

Here's what I think it should be:

```
bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const {
    return (nodePosition == p.nodePosition);
}
```

Comment: Oh didn't even notice that. Not sure if it will help in this case though.

Comment: @RichardRasmussen, if that does not fix your problem, you should  post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: I think this answer *should* fix it. I guess that the OP's code did not compile, because of `if (nodePosition == llist.begin())`, comparing an iterator object to a pointer `Node<E>* `

Comment: @A.S.H that's what I'm trying to fix here. I'm not really sure what to compare the iterator to here.

Comment: @RichardRasmussen how about `if(nodePosition == llist.begin().nodePosition)` ? Or, if you apply Sahu''s fix to your `==` operator, then you could say: `if(llist.begin() == *this)`

Comment: @A.S.H I get  Error C2228 left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union when trying to use llist.begin()

Comment: @RichardRasmussen ok it obviously should be `llist->begin()`

Comment: @A.S.H Would I have to forward declare the == overload? I now get 
Error  C2679   binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'List<int>::Iterator<E>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97097/discussion-between-richard-rasmussen-and-a-s-h).